# replacement for a if statement or the use of a collection

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, collections, excel-2013

Earlier I asked a question where I couldn't get a correct answer. I think I couldn't express myself properly. This is a problem I am facing:

```
Sub organize()

    Dim GroupID(1 To 30) As String
    Dim GroupAanwezig As Long
    Dim class As String
    Dim i, j, t, totally, countCol As Integer
    Dim GroupenCol As New Collection

    i = 1
    t = 1

    rn_totallist = Worksheets("totallist").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    nxA_9N4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_9N4")

    nxA_1A2A = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1A2A")
    nxA_1A2B = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1A2B")
    nxA_2A2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_2A2")

    nxA_2A3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_2A3")
    nxA_3A3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_3A3")

    nxA_1B4A = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1B4A")
    nxA_1B4B = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1B4B")
    nxA_1B4C = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1B4C")
    nxA_1B4D = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1B4D")

    nxA_2G4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_2G4")
    nxA_3G4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_3G4")
    nxA_4G4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_4G4")

    nxA_2A4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_2A4")
    nxA_3A4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_3A4")
    nxA_4A4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_4A4")

    nxA_1E3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1E3")
    nxA_1E4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_1E4")

    nxA_2E4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_2E4")
    nxA_3e3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_3E3")
    nxA_3e4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_3E4")
    nxA_4e4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("totallist").Range("G2:G" & rn_totallist), "xA_4E4")

    totalstd = nxA_9N4 + nxA_1A2A + nxA_1A2B + nxA_2A2 + nxA_2A3 + nxA_3A3 + nxA_1B4A + nxA_1B4B + nxA_1B4C + nxA_1B4D + nxA_2G4 + nxA_3G4 + nxA_4G4 + nxA_2A4 + nxA_3A4 + nxA_4A4 + nxA_1E3 + nxA_1E4 + nxA_2E4 + nxA_3e3 + nxA_3e4 + nxA_4e4

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_9N4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1A2A
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1A2B
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_2A2

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_2A3
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_3A3

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1B4A
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1B4B
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1B4C
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1B4D

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_2G4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_3G4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_4G4

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_2A4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_3A4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_4A4

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1E3
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_1E4

     GroupenCol.Add nxA_2E4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_3e3
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_3e4
     GroupenCol.Add nxA_4e4

        LastRow = Sheets("BLS").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

          For i = 2 To LastRow
            LastCol = Sheets("BLS").Cells(i, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For j = 2 To LastCol
                class = Sheets("BLS").Cells(i, j).Value
                GroupAanwezig = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:D18"), class)
                BLSers = Sheets("BLS").Cells(i, 1).Value

            If InStr(nshow, class) = 0 Then
            GroupID(t) = class
            nshow = nshow & " " & GroupAanwezig & " " & t & " " & GroupID(t) & vbCrLf
            t = t + 1
            End If

            countCol = Sheets("BLS").Cells(i, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lastcolumn = countCol - 1


            Select Case lastcolumn
                Case Is = 0
                    'MsgBox "EMPTY"
                Case Is = 1
                    totally = lastcolumn * 30

                Case Is = 2
                    totally = ((lastcolumn * 10) - 5) * 2

                Case Is = 3
                    totally = lastcolumn * 10

                    nclass = "n" + class
                     MsgBox nclass
                     '---------------------------------------------------------
                     'there has to be a faster way to do the if-statement below.
                     '---------------------------------------------------------
                     If class = "xA_9N4" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_9N4
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_4A4" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_4A4
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_3A4" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_3A4
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_1B4B" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_1B4B
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_1A2B" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_1A2B
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_2A4" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_2A4
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_2E4" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_2E4
                     End If
                     If class = "xA_1E3" Then
                        MsgBox nxA_1E3
                     End If
                     '--------------------------------------------------------
            End Select
    End Sub
```

In the last case (case is = 3) there is a **if-statement**. This **if statement** is a shor version (this needs to be repeated in case 0, case 1 and case 2). I need to do something with the returned value *(for example) nxA_9N4*. In an earlier attempt to solve a problem I got help from:

> engineersmnky he told me to use a collection.

I used a collection but still :(.

---

Comment answers: 
-if a cell.value is has the same value as the class (which is always the case) then I will  return the value from another sheet. This value counts the groups/classes called "xA4A" and returns the countvalue as nxA4A. with the ifstatement I would like to know if class = "xA4A" then give me the count of nxA4A.

By the way eval function doesn't work in 2013.

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? When executing the procedure, does the logic work when expected and display a message box?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with that if statement?

Comment: It seems [z̫͋](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3484251/z%CC%AB%CD%8B) was right. I tested my answer in VBS without problem, but VBA for excel is lacking, though it seems to work in access : /... redacted.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems you were pretty close. I've modified the `GroupenCol.Add`'s to include a second parameter ( a key ), which is a string version of the first, without the n:

    `GroupenCol.Add nxA_9N4, "xA_9N4"`

Then, instead of the `If`s, I used

    `MsgBox GroupenCol.Item( class )`

However, I'll hold off on an answer until it's tested proper in Excel.

re: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241522(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Many thanks It works :) insufficient memory was the error I was getting. It had to do with the quotes I forgot adding... Thanks barrowc and the rest of you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Collection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006(v=vs.60).aspx) method, you'll see it can take up to 4 parameters. The first is the object to be added (as you're doing already) but the second optional parameter is the key - a unique string value used to identify this object in the collection.

So, if you add items into the collection like this:

`GroupenCol.Add nxA_9N4, "xA_9N4"`

and you have the required string value in a variable called "class", you could then access the collection like this:

`MsgBox GroupenCol(class)`

or this:

`MsgBox GroupenCol.Item(class)`

(These are equivalent because `Item` is the default property of a `Collection`)